# How to change CSS style.display with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

in my webpage the menu has a structure like this:

```
<nav id="menu">
      <label for="tm" id="toggle-menu">Menù <span class="drop-icon">▾</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="tm">
      <ul class="main-menu clearfix">
        <li><a href="http://www.internalsite.lab/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transfer 
            <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm1">▾</label>
            </a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sm1">
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="data.html">internal data</a></li>
                <li><a href="data_ext.html">external data</a></li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="imp"><a href="necessary.html">Necessary Data</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

and a CSS like this:

```
    #menu .main-menu {
      display: block;
    }

    #menu li, 
    #toggle-menu,
    #menu a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
    }  

    #menu .main-menu li.imp{
      display: none;
    }

    #menu .main-menu li{
        background-color: #197dd1;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

I would like to change the display none of the #menu .main-menu li.imp into block if a certain condition occurs, for this reason i have a js code like this

```
<script "application/javascript">
var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $value; ?>";
if( value== "true") { document.getElementsByClassName('imp').style.display = 'block';}
</script>
```

I'am sure that value is equal true, but it does not work.

Any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Why do you expect `document.getElementsByClassName('imp')` to have a `style` property with a `display` setter? Also, `var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $value; ?>";` isn’t guaranteed to work. Please see [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168214/4642212).

Comment: Shouldn't `if( value== "true")` be `if( javaScriptVar == "true")`? I not, then where does `value` come from and what's the point of `javaScriptVar`? And does `$value` contain a boolean (true) or the string literal "true"? If it's a boolean, then `echo $value` would output `1`, not the string "true".

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you but if i put 
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('imp');
alert(elems.length)
i obtain 0, is a problem of the HTML tag?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` is returning a node list rather than a single element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('imp').style.display = 'block'
```

is code that would only affect a single element... it cannot work with a node list. You either would need to loop through the node list and apply this to each individual item, or change `document.getElementsByClassName` to something like `document.getElementById` that would only return one item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function **getElements**ByClassName, this returns a node list / HtmlCollections, you have to iterate the nodes.**strong text**

for example, the id of elements is unique and you use **getElement**Byid this returns a just node.

You can trie:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.imp').forEach(function(e) {
    e.style.display = 'none'
})
```